# Does the Cantor set admit structure of $\Delta$-complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As the question title suggests, does the Cantor set admit the structure of a $\Delta$-complex?

Comment: The Cantor Set is not locally connected because it is an infinite product $\mathbf 2^\Bbb N$ of disconnected spaces. But every $\Delta$-complex is locally connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A totally disconnected $\Delta$-complex could only have 0-simplices and hence would be discrete, but the Cantor set is not discrete.